# TYPO3: Indexed Search plugin limited to a single page + subpages

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x, tx-indexed-search

I'm using TYPO3 11.5.27 and the indexed_search extension.

Is it possible to limit the search to only a page and relative subpages?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of `ext:indexed_search` there is a hint at the setting [`rootPidList`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/11.5/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#root-pid-list):

```
By "root page" we mean a website root defined by a TypoScript template! 
If you just want to search in branches of your site, 
use the possibility of searching in levels.
```

As I understand you should use the settings [`displayLevel1Sections`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/11.5/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#display-level-1-sections), [`displayLevel2Sections`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/11.5/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#display-level-2-sections) and [`displayLevelxAllSections`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/11.5/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#display-level-x-all-types) to iterate level to level to the start of the branch you want search results from.
Probably you can preset these values in POST parameters to start your search in a page branch starting with a page at a higher level than the web root.

Comment: Hi Peter & Bernd Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of each page there is the toggle "Include in Search" in the "Behaviour" tab. There you can switch indexing off or on for every page.

I'm not aware of a recursive function to do so for an entire subtree.

What you could do (but please with caution!):

- Backup your database. Really!
- Switch off indexing for **every** page directly in the database with this SQL query:
  `UPDATE pages SET no_search = 1;`
- Turn indexing on in the page settings for every desired page
- truncate all indexed_search database tables:

  ```
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_phash;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_fulltext;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_rel;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_words;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_section;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_grlist;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_debug;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_config;
   TRUNCATE TABLE index_stat_word;
  ```

After that you need to fill the search index again.

For pages that will be created in the future you can turn off indexing by default with this TSConfig:
`TCAdefaults.pages.no_search = 1`

If you need a newly created page in the index, you need to switch indexing on manually for that page.